# On smallest convex m-gons that contain a given n-gon where m<n

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

1. Given a convex n-gon region P, and an m less than n, will the least area convex m-gon Q that contains P be such that an edge of Q coincides with an edge of P (in other words Q cannot be such that P touches it only at isolated points)? I have no proof or counter.
2. Same question as above with 'perimeter' replacing 'area'.

A natural approach for both questions would be to select m from among the n edges of P, to extend them into lines and find the intersection of half-planes they give - and repeat for all such m-subsets. Not sure how close to optimal the answer would be (the method itself looks inefficient).

As special cases, one can try to characterize and find the least area/perimeter triangles and convex quadrilaterals that contain P.

Comment: What would you get through a *natural approach* if you seek for a triangle containing a paerallelogram?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Does this also mean that there is no 'lemma' that could  simplify the search for the containing m-gon?